# Can't find namespace for Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Can't find namespace:

```
 using Windows.Media.Capture;
```

in my Visual Studio 2013.

Usings in WMAppManifest.xml:

ID_CAP_IDENTITY_CAMERA;

ID_CAP_MCROPHONE;

Comment: Check if you've referenced all relevant DLLs. It looks like to require Windows 8.1. Maybe it could also need Windows SDK or something. See also https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

Comment: plase specify what windows phone version is your project

Comment: maybe, Windows.Media.Capture is only for "Windows Market apps", not "Windows Phone apps"?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try the following: `using System.Windows.Media.Capture`

I think this namespace is part of the System.Windows.dll, so just make sure that you've referenced it.